# Magento does not redirect when using a credit card with paypal payments pro, but the express option redirects fine

Tags: magento, redirect, paypal, payment-gateway, magento-1.8

I did not set this up, we don't really have a test area, unfortunately the site is live and we are trying to fix something the developer left undone/untested. We are using Magento version: 1.8.0.0. I have switched on and off many different settings and have not gotten any good results. It seems odd that I followed a tutorial to check the settings and everything matches up and the express portion works fine and the credit card portion does not redirect and it just sits there and does nothing = failure. Can you please make suggestions on what the problem might be or if I need to contact PayPal, what can I suggest to them the problem might be if it is on their end. I am not entirely familiar with setting up Magento payment gateways.

Thank you for any help you can give us,

Tracy

Answer (score 0):

Not a Magento user nor dev (disclaimer).

Redirect where? Your "success/failure" page or to Paypal (like in Express Checkout)?

Credit card (type of payment) won't/shouldn't redirect to Paypal, you are essentially sending the card data you collected at your web app and sending it off to Paypal for processing (try to AUTHORIZE and/or CAPTURE funds), and waiting for a response to that request. User doesn't leave your site.

Do you have a Paypal Manager account..if IINM, you *should* if you have a "Pro" account that allows you to collect credit card data at your site (though this is something Paypal folk can better answer)? It can be helpful to check if your system is actually sending the request to Paypal (gateway). Or perhaps an error log in Magento?

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, and found that the problem was in the layout for checkout.xml in the iPhone template.

I added the following piece (without the ** marks) to app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/checkout.xml

```
<checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Overview</label>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
            <label>Items Before</label>
        </block>
        **<block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
            <label>Items After</label>
        </block>**
        <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

Hope that helps others

Cheers
Twan